# HTML appearance in the email is different than in browser

Tags: html, css

I've the below html code, that I want to use it as template for sending emails in my app:

```css
        .card-label {
            background-color: rgb(229, 232, 237);
            border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px;
            color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 1em 0px 0px;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 2;
            font-family: Inter,sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            line-height: 1.4;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }
        .card {
            display: block;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 16px 16px;
            background: rgb(8, 27, 75);
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 1em;
            white-space: normal;
            overflow-wrap: normal;
            font-family: "JetBrains Mono", sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.4em;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="card-label">
        {{.Name}}
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        {{.Message}}
    </div>

    <a href="https://wa.me/{{.Number}}">الرد برسالة واتس!</a>
```

The full file is:

```html
<!-- template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .card-label {
            background-color: rgb(229, 232, 237);
            border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px;
            color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 1em 0px 0px;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 2;
            font-family: Inter,sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            line-height: 1.4;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }
        .card {
            display: block;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 16px 16px;
            background: rgb(8, 27, 75);
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 1em;
            white-space: normal;
            overflow-wrap: normal;
            font-family: "JetBrains Mono", sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.4em;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-label">
        {{.Name}}
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        {{.Message}}
    </div>

    <a href="https://wa.me/{{.Number}}">الرد برسالة واتس!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The file looks nice in the browser, but the styling looks to be broken in the email, as shown below:

[image]

What could be the issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: HTML in emails was always much more restricted and will be forever much more restricted. You never can work around. Your best bet is to test every common mail-system for appearance. As a rule of thumb: you should always use the `style` attribute in HTML-tags using simple CSS1 in eMails.

Comment: This might also be helpful to check what can work and what not: https://www.caniemail.com/